# Why are all my iATS recurring payments for EFT/ACH marked as "pending incomplete transaction"?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, iats, payment

This occured today, after upgrade from 4.6 to 4.7. The recurring credit cards appear to be updating properly in civiCRM, but not the EFT/ACH. More importantly, it also appears that the transactions in question did not transact at iatspayment.com. Is my EFT payment processor not set up properly?

I am running Civi 4.7.22 and iATS extension version 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pending / Incomplete is expected for ACHEFT - it can stay in that status for days depending on when iATS connects with the bank/credit union the debit account is with.

On iATSPayments.com -> look under Journal -> ACHEFT transactions -> ACHEFT details

Next make sure your recurring jobs are running. Esp the ACHEFT verify one -> that's the one that will check w/ iATS if any of the pending / incomplete ACHEFT can be updated to completed in CiviCRM.

Comment: All jobs running (all fired this mornign). At iATSPayments, there is no batch list for ACH today. Nothing rejected, nothing returned, nothing approved, nothing in batch list. The recurring log in scheduled jobs reports "Success: OK for all the EFTs in question, so all seem to have been processed by CiviCRM.

Comment: And you are positive the agent code listed in the ACHEFT payment processor config (in CiviCRM) matches the one you log in with on iATSPayments.com?

Comment: Okay, my mistake. There is a list of the pending transactions in iATSPayments admin area for ACHEFT. The result column reads like this: "ToBeSend:ToBeSent". This is under the ACHEFT "Details" list. Not directly under the "List Batches". Sorry. I missed that. So is it all good? Just wait for the ACHEFT to clear and it should be updated in CiviCRM?

Comment: Ok phew! That makes more sense; ToBeSend means iATS still needs to submit the details to the Bank; so all good (thus far). Since it's Friday - check in on Monday / or even Tuesday.